# Convert Maven project to Netbeans project

Tags: java, maven, plugins, netbeans

When ever I open up a [Maven project](http://www.disasterarea.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/spannersws.zip) in Netbeans and try do a "Priming Build" or normal "Build" it fails. It either gets stuck downloading dependencies or throws errors. Is there a plugin or something that can convert Maven projects to Netbeans projects? Even if you have to manually download the dependencies...

This is one of the errors I get:

> Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for
>
> org.dontpanic:spannersws:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
>   'build.plugins.plugin.version' for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 66,
>   column 21
>
> It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten
>   the stability of your build.
>
> For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support
>   building such malformed projects.

Comment: Would you like to solve the Maven build problems or would you like to go to Netbeans?

Comment: I use Netbeans all the time so essentially, what "I" need is to get maven projects (downloadable from blogs etc) to run on Netbeans. The plugin idea is just one way of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans just opens Maven projects. You don't need to convert them. 
What are you expecting is a Maven problem. It seems that pom.xml is broken.
I think that the project was prepared on Maven 2. Newest Netbeans has Maven 3 included. Try to fix pom.xml following the directions or download Maven 2 and switch Maven version in Netbeans from embedded to external.

I'd suggest fixing pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans natively supports Maven projects. The error message isn't an error. It's just a warning that started appearing in Maven after version 3 to help people configure their projects better.

Comment: What happens if you run it just with Maven? (`mvn clean install` from the command line)